# Search practitoner by organisation

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir, smart-on-fhir

How do i search Practitioners in a department/organization e.g prov,dep,gov on FHIR server. i want to display only practitioners from a particular organization.

Tried this "GET [base]/Practitioner?Organization=Organization/{_id}" and did not return any results.

Answer (score 2):

You can only search a resource based on information in that resource, and more specifically, using search parameters defined for the resource.  Practitioner doesn't capture any information about 'organization' and doesn't have a search parameter called "Organization".  (Side point - search parameter names are almost always lower-case.)

Practitioner represents a professional *independent* of who they work for or what role they're acting in.  The PractitionerRole resource is what you need.  It represents the combination of "who?" (practitioner), "on-behalf-of whom?" (organization), and "wearing which hat?" (code).  Not all aspects will be present/relevant in all instances, but in your case you'd have both organization and practitioner.

Comment: Oh okay, so if i wanted to build a relationship between Practitioner and Organization i should do it in the PractitionerRole and query that everytime i wanted to return the list of practitioners that work for a particular Organization?

Comment: You would need to use reverse chaining:
GET [base]/Practitioner?_has:PractitionerRole:practitioner:organization=Organization/{_id}.  Give me a practitioner, who has a practitioner role pointing to this practitioner with an organization of {_id}